# Can I deploy multiple build versions using the same bamboo deployment plan?

Tags: deployment, bamboo

I would like to create a single bamboo deployment plan to deploy multiple versions of an artifact.

Each supported version has a maintenance branch in git.

Bamboo supports the creation of a single build plan that can be applied to many branches.

Can this be transferred to the deployment project, in which the deployment would be identical, parameterized only by the version.

Answer (score 2):

Deployment plans are used for deploying artifacts, which are created by existing bamboo build jobs. So if you have bamboo build jobs, which create the different versions of your artifact, you can easily reuse your existing deployment plan.

I assuming a bamboo build plan (with multiple builds either due to updates or due to different branches, thus containing different versions of your software) and a working deployment plan.

You can then use your deployment plan and start a deployment by clicking on that cloud icon, select a release to deploy "Create new release from build result", choose the branch and/or correct build number of the build, give your child a meaningful name and deploy the newly created release of your software. However this mean, that at a given time you'll have only a single version deployed.

If you want to deploy multiple version simultaneously you should clone your existing environment of the deployment plan. Otherwise you wouln't be able to track which version (release) of your software is deployed.

Comment: Thanks. I do want to deploy multiple versions, and I have cloned the deployment projects. This gets pretty unmaintainable pretty quickly though. Say we are maintaining 3 versions of a product (current + 2 old), and they are each deployed on 3 environments (development, staging and prod), that is 9 deployment configurations. If something changes then ... :(

Comment: We're facing a similar issue. As soon as Configuration as Code will be available for deployment plans too, it wont be a big deal anymore. Until then, I recommend using mostly identical builds which are configured by bamboo variables. Then you can clone the environments and update only the variables - but i totally agree with you.

Comment: Did you try configuration as code yet? We've just upgraded to 6.2 but I am yet to try it. Would be interesting to hear someone else's experience

Comment: Do you know how to rollback multiple deployments at same time in bamboo?